# Fancybox navigation does not work with html grouped items

Tags: navigation, fancybox

what i have is a fancybox where linked items are html content:
my html links are:

```
<a class="various1" href="#inline1">
<a class="various1" href="#inline2">
<a class="various1" href="#inline3">
```

and the linked items are:

```
<div style="display: none;">
   <div id="inline1">html content</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;">
   <div id="inline2">html content</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;">
   <div id="inline3">html content</div>
</div>
```

my jquery call to fancybox is:

```
$(".various1").fancybox({
    'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
});
```

The problem is that next/back buttons do not work, the divs "fancybox-right/left" do not get rendered. I would like to have such a functionality.

Normally, if i chose to link to images then since .various1 is class of all links, the navigation next/back would appear.

This does not happen if i link to html content, is there something i am missing or any workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add the same `rel` attribute for your gallery to work

```
<a class="various1" rel="group" href="#inline1">
<a class="various1" rel="group" href="#inline2">
<a class="various1" rel="group" href="#inline3">
```